# Problema com JS/PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou tentando fazer um chat pra minha intranet e o problema é o seguinte, o meu código em JS não está captando o retorno via echo do PHP, logo, a função não apaga o texto que a pessoa escreve no chat após o enter, poderiam me ajudar?

Segue os códigos:

submit.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['mensagem'])){
    include("../conectaBanco.php");

    $mensagem = strip_tags(trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mensagem', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
    $de = (int)$_POST['de'];
    $para = (int)$_POST['para'];
    $tempo = time();

    if($mensagem != ''){
        $insert = "INSERT INTO mensagens (id_de, id_para, mensagem, time, lido) VALUES ('$de','$para','$mensagem','$tempo','0')";
        if($res = mysqli_query($conn, $insert)){
            echo 'ok';
        }else{
            echo 'no';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

function.js

```
    jQuery('body').on('keyup', '.msg', function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        var texto = jQuery(this).val();
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        var split = id.split(':');
        var para = Number(split[1]);

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './sys/submit.php',
            data: {mensagem:texto, de: userOnline, para: para},
            sucess: function(retorno){
                if(retorno == 'ok'){
                    jQuery('.msg').val('');
                }else{
                    alert('Ocorreu um erro ao enviar a mensagem :(');
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Ocorreu um erro ao enviar a mensagem :(');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Através do Firebug percebi que o submit.php está funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu erro é de escrita, o callback deve ser **success** e não sucess!

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

Na tua requisição ajax, tens o callback `sucess` que não existe, certo seria `success`